# Entity Framework 4 (CTP 5) concurrency

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

ever since I read about Code-First I find out there might be a problem with this (although its just a preview) I have 2 problem with EF4 CTP5 release as folowing:

As it said "New Change Tracking API"
    but it dose't tracking changes i
    guess. In comparison with LINQ to SQL I
    bring an example to see what
    each method react:

LINQ to SQL:

```
Dim db2 As New LINQDataContext
Dim db3 As New LINQDataContext

db2.Product.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.ID = 100).Name = "Change1"
db3.Product.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.ID = 100).Name = "Change2"

db2.SubmitChanges()
db3.SubmitChanges()
```

EF 4 CTP5:

```
Dim db2 As New ProductContext
Dim db3 As New ProductContext

db2.Product.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.ID = 100).Name = "Change1"
db3.Product.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.ID = 100).Name = "Change2"

db2.SaveChanges()
db3.SaveChanges()
```

These codes are only different in their Contexts. In LINQ to SQL, the second SubmitChanges will rise an exception of **"Row not found or changed."**, but in EF it will ignore the changes and continue changing the row twice, which I think is bad because we must consider concurrency, right?

Comment: You should say [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx). There are other flavors of LINQ: [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx), that happens to be in EF, [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), ye olde [Linq to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) and many other flavors.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are completely right about it, it was midnight so it wasn't completely my fault ;)

Comment: I remove my second question and place it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690397/entity-framework-4-ctp-5-unwisely-queries-in-comparison-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Focusing on your first comparison, I believe that you have some optimistic concurrency checking on by default in LINQ to SQL. IN EF, you have to explicitly mark any properties that you want to be checked for concurrency. Since you most likely have not done that for the Name property, EF doesn't care that someone changed the Product name in another database command.

I also want to point out that this isn't specifcally a code first behavior but it is a behaviour throughout EF. If you create an Entity Data Model, you also have to expclitily mark properties for concurrency checking.

If you are using the fluent API, look for IsConcurrencyToken as an attribute to set on a property. If you are using annotation, take a look at ConcurrencyCheckAttribute.

hth
julie